# Acknowleding referee suggestions after rejection

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper to a conference, it got rejected but I received valuable feedback. After implementing the suggested changes, I am submitting the manuscript to a different conference but I would like to thank the referees from the previous conference.

If I just write "We thank the reviewers for their invaluable suggestions" then it might be confusing for the referees of the current (second) conference.

What are you doing in such a situation?

Comment: "We thank 4 anonymous reviewers." By adding the number it often gives the appropriate information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

> We would like to thank X and Y for their review of a previous version of this manuscript

Comment: That would work nicely if one knew their names...

Comment: Nothing stops you from putting "anonymous" in there.

Comment: nothiing stops you from leaving X and Y: _We would like to thank X and Y for their review of a previous version of this manuscript. We unfortunately do not know their names, but this does not decrease our gratitude._ :D

Comment: @Michael I like the anonymous suggestions, thank you